# <video> rendered inside <template> shows black for webcam stream (Safari 14.0.3 only)

Tags: javascript, html, safari, html5-video, getusermedia

Important notice - this is happening **only on Safari 14.0.3**!

After macOS and Safari update (14.0 -> 14.0.3) video stream from the webcam I'm getting using `navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia` shows only black inside `<video>` for some time and updates to actual video at some point (sometimes not). This  is situated inside `<template>` which I add to DOM using JavaScript.

In short:

```
<template><video></video></template> (shows black)
<video></video> (shows ok)
```

JsFiddle with the reproducible demo - https://jsfiddle.net/alex_oliynyk/402ed6wq/54/

Gif with the issue - https://share.getcloudapp.com/2NuElvYl

Also, I can confirm that video is actually playing fine. This is part of the app where I send frames from the video to the backend for processing and I get a successful response. This means that frames are not just black rectangulars but are proper images.

Any idea how to can I make the video appear right away?

Cheers!

UPD: fixed typo in `<template>`

Comment: I can repro, you can report at https://bugs.webkit.org/ Note that [requesting PiP](https://jsfiddle.net/Lsmh0qu2/) or [fullscreen](https://jsfiddle.net/Lsmh0qu2/1/) makes the video render correctly...

Comment: Great, thanks for the pointer to their bug tracker!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a decent amount of back-and-forth, I've found a workaround to make it work.

Basically, when `getUserMedia` is called I programmatically create a video tag, add a video stream to it, add it to the DOM. Having container `div` helps a lot to position it in the right spot.

Working demo - https://jsfiddle.net/alex_oliynyk/402ed6wq/95/

Also submitted the [bug report](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=222115) for the WebKit team.

Best,

Comment: Thanks for sharing this! The demo code works perfectly in MacOS Safari but still shows a black screen in iOS Safari (v15.3.1). Would appreciate any input on the same. Thanks!